# Find and delete column

Tags: excel, vba, find

I want to find text in a column and if found delete the corresponding column.

It deletes the first found column but then errors on next iteration.

When I delete the column the FindNext method gives an error.

> Unable to get the FindNext property of the Range Class

```vb
Private Sub ClearInPlanCells(strSearch As String, wrkSheetName As String)
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Worksheets(wrkSheetName).Cells
        Set rngFound = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strAddr = rngFound.Address
            Set rngFound = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
           ' On Error Resume Next
            Do
                'MsgBox (rngFound.Address)
                Sheets(wrkSheetName).Columns(rngFound.Column).EntireColumn.Delete
                Set rngFound = .FindNext(rngFound)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strAddr
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: `Sheets(wrkSheetName).Columns(rngFound.Column).EntireColumn` is the same as `rngFound.EntireColumn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `FindNext(After:=rngFound)` because you've deleted `rngFound`. If you step through, you'll see `rngFound` turns into `<object required>` after you delete it. I suggest saving all of the columns into a variable and then deleting them after the loop.

```vb
Sub ClearInPlanCells(strSearch As String, wrkSheet As Worksheet)
    
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim DeleteColumns As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With wrkSheet.Cells
        Set rngFound = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            Dim strAddr As String
            strAddr = rngFound.Address
            
            Do
                If DeleteColumns Is Nothing Then
                    Set DeleteColumns = rngFound.EntireColumn
                Else
                    Set DeleteColumns = Union(DeleteColumns, rngFound.EntireColumn)
                End If
                
                Set rngFound = .FindNext(rngFound)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strAddr
            
        End If
        
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If Not DeleteColumns Is Nothing Then DeleteColumns.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

I changed parameter `wrkSheetName As String` into `wrkSheet As Worksheet` because it makes more sense to pass the worksheet object into the sub directly, and avoid the issue of not knowing which workbook the sheet name belongs to.

Comment: thanks @Toddleson - That's exactly where I was going wrong.. I just couldnt figure out how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Criteria Columns

**A Simple Test**

```vb
Sub DeleteCriteriaColumnsTEST()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    DeleteCriteriaColumns wb, "Sheet1", "Yes"

End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub DeleteCriteriaColumns( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal WorksheetID As Variant, _
        ByVal SearchString As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetID)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange

    Dim urg As Range, crg As Range, cel As Range
    
    For Each crg In rg.Columns
        Set cel = crg.Find(SearchString, , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = cel Else Set urg = Union(urg, cel)
        End If
    Next crg

    If Not urg Is Nothing Then urg.EntireColumn.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```